# How to work with temporary objects CoreData?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord

I use lib MagicalRecord (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) for CoreData.framework.

I don't understand how to work with temporary objects.

How to create NSManagedContext for temporary objects and whether to delete each NSManagedObject after closing controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All objects created on a context are temporary objects and they become permanent when you save that context. So to discard them, you just don't save that context.

To create a new (temporary) context assuming you use Apple's Core Data Stack:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tempChildContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
tempChildContext.parentContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

To save changes, you need to do two saves, one on the temporary context and then push it into the main context.

```
[tempChildContext performBlock:^{
   // do something that takes some time asynchronously using the temp context

   // push to parent
   NSError *error;
   if (![tempChildContext save:&error])
   {
      // handle error
   }

   // save parent to disk asynchronously
   [self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
      NSError *error;
      if (![self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&amp;error])
      {
         // handle error
      }
   }];
}];
```

I am sorry, I don't remember how to do it with MagicalRecord, but MR is just a wrapper around CoreData, so it will work. I stopped using MR on my first CoreData project. I suggest you read this: [Multi-Context CoreData](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/).